# Update list using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two classes, `Student` and `Details`.

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentD { get; set; } // PK
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string StudentType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Details> Details { get; set; } // FK
}
public class Details
{
    [Key]
    public int DetailsID { get; set; } // PK
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; } // FK
}
```

I display the list of all students on the web page and I would like to allow the editing of student details for the selected student.

```
<form method="post">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Details[0].Name) </th>
            <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Details[0].Value) </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Details)
    {
        <tr>
        <td> <input type="hidden" asp-for=@item.DetailsID /> </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Property) </td>
        <td contenteditable='true'> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value) </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
</form>
```

The page model is as below,

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly TestEFCore.Data.TestEFCoreContext _context;
    public EditModel(TestEFCore.Data.TestEFCoreContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public IList<TestEFCore.Models.Details> Details { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null) { return NotFound(); }
        Detailss = await _context.Details.Where(m => m.StudentID == id).ToListAsync();
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return Page(); }

        _context.Attach(Details).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try { await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) { throw; }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

When a student is selected, I then display the details in a HTML table and would like EF Core to keep track of changes in the HTML table. To achieve this, I create an `IList` of `Details` and display it, but when the user updates any values, I get an error that the `IList` doesn't exist in the model which I can understand because the model only has DB table column info and not the `IList` of rows as such.

Would anyone be able to suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: I've added my sample test code for clarity

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after changing the type as below, from `IList` to `List`

```
[BindProperty]
public List<TestEFCore.Models.Details> Details { get; set; }
```